# magento2 plugin and str_replace

Tags: magento2.3

In file module magento have function

```
public function formatPrecision(
    $price,
    $precision,
    $options = [],
    $includeContainer = true,
    $addBrackets = false
) {
    if (!isset($options['precision'])) {
        $options['precision'] = $precision;
    }
    if ($includeContainer) {
        return '<span class="price">' . ($addBrackets ? '[' : '') . $this->formatTxt(
            $price,
            $options
        ) . ($addBrackets ? ']' : '') . '</span>';
    }
    return $this->formatTxt($price, $options);
}
```

I write di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
    <plugin name="afterFormatPrecision" type="Commercers\PriceItemprop\Plugin\Currency" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

And i have afterFormatPrecision

```
public function afterFormatPrecision(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $subject
){
    return str_replace('<span class="price">','<span class="price" itemprop="price">','<span class="price">');
}
```

But function after not working. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your after plugin arguments are wrong, you need to add the $result argument in order to make a replacement.

Try the following:

```
public function afterFormatPrecision(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $subject,
    $result
){
    return str_replace('<span class="price">','<span class="price" itemprop="price">', $result);
}
```

Source: [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#after-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't allow this (itemprop) attribute, that's why when passing content to **escapeHtml** who remove your **itemprop** attribute. Here is the allowed attribute list:

```
private $allowedAttributes = ['id', 'class', 'href', 'title', 'style'];
```

Check the following class:
**vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php**

```
private function removeNotAllowedAttributes(\DOMDocument $domDocument)
{
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($domDocument);
    $nodes = $xpath->query(
        '//@*[name() != \'' . implode('\' and name() != \'', $this->allowedAttributes) . '\']'
    );
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeAttribute($node->nodeName);
    }

    foreach ($this->notAllowedAttributes as $tag => $attributes) {
        $nodes = $xpath->query(
            '//@*[name() =\'' . implode('\' or name() = \'', $attributes) . '\']'
            . '[parent::node()[name() = \'' . $tag . '\']]'
        );
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $node->parentNode->removeAttribute($node->nodeName);
        }
    }
}
```

You can overwrite following phtml for your modification:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml**